# Как перезапустить Apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Как перезапустить Apache?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Нужно выполнить команду `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Comment: Обязательно под рутом.

Comment: в убунту "нету" рута, там немного другая политика безопасности

Comment: Что значит нету рута? Глупости какие-то :) Сижу в убунте и все там на месте ;)

Comment: фактически его нету! в убунте палитика другая поэтому рутом его назвать тяжело! реальное понятие рут идёт от юникса. больше читай, чувак!:))

Answer (score 8):

Это "жёсткий" перезапуск:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Перезапуск, не убивая процесс, а просто применение новой конфигурации:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 6):

Для перезапуска используйте:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Подробнее узнать о команде можно вызвав справку:

```
man apache2ctl
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

более подробно тут: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/6358/how-do-you-restart-apache

Answer (score 3):

Если установлен [`systemd`](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/systemd), то можно перезапустить с помощь него:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```